# Chain rule for Newton-derivative

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis

I'm looking for properties of the *Newton-derivative*, defined as follows: A function $F \colon X \to Y$ is Newton differentiable at $x\in X$ if there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and a function $G\colon B_\varepsilon(x) \to L(X,Y)$ such that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{y\to0} \frac{\|F(x + y) -F(x) -G(x+y)[y]\|_Y}{\|y\|_X} = 0.
\end{align*}

$G$ is called Newton-derivative.  Can you provide me with a proof (or any reference) for a chain rule for this differential?

Actually, I need to know about the Newton-derivative of the function 
\begin{align*}
L^2(\Omega) \ni u \mapsto \max(-1,\min(1,u)), 
\end{align*}
which hopefully exists... Thanks a lot, Malte.

Comment: I assume that $v+y$ should be something else, because $v$ is undefined, but it looks like this is another name for the [Fréchet dferivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative).

Comment: It was a typo. I edited the question. And regarding your comment with the Fréchet derivative, I think it's a little weaker and especially only a local property

Comment: To anybody who has doubts: This is not the Frechet derivative and the $x+y$ in the argument of G is correct. More to the question: First, the Newton derivative is not unique. It could be that a Newton derivative in this case may be u where it is between -1 and +1 and zero elsewhere but I remember vaguely that there may be a problem with the norms here... (Buzzword "norm gap", probably in a paper by Kunisch or Ulbrich).

Comment: That's a standard result that can be found in, e.g., the books by Ulbrich (Theorem 3.69), Ito and Kunisch (Lemma 8.4), or (shameless plug) [my lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04180) (Theorem 9.2). Note that there is no chain rule for two Gâteaux differentiable functions. And a(!) Newton derivative is given by the pointwise multiplication with $v(x) = 1$ if $u(x)\in [-1,1]$ and $0$ else -- *iff*, as @Dirk writes, your function is considered as mapping to $L^p$ for $p<2$, see again the mentioned literature. (For both results, the proof is virtually the same as for Fréchet derivatives.)

Comment: Thank you both for your remarks and this extensive literature! I consider this question solved.